Moderator Declined Flag to Merge Questions due to Lack of Evidence to Support It
Yesterday, as per this thread, I flagged this question to be merged with this one since they were exact duplicates and the answers to the duplicate question would still make perfect sense to the original one as well. But, a moderator declined my flag stating that there was not enough evidence to support it. Below is the message shown:

Now, I am wondering, why was my flag declined when merging both the questions seems to be a good choice? What exactly is the problem here? Did I fail to phrase my request correctly? Or is it a bad idea to merge both these questions?

Given that a moderator has declined the flag you could ask in this room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office if a moderator could explain it to you.  I'm not sure the rest of us can really guess what the moderator's reasoning was.

As I am the moderator who dealt with that flag:  merges are rare.  Generally speaking, I only use merges if a single user has asked the same question multiple times and gotten multiple answers from different people.  Unlike many other moderator actions (closure, locking, deleting, etc), merging is not reversible, so if a merge is made in error, it cannot be easily fixed.  My general preference is to close questions as duplicates, rather than merging them.
In this particular case, there are probably at least a dozen other duplicates of the question on the site which could (perhaps) be merged into the proposed merge target.  But having those other questions around, closed as duplicates, actually makes the dupe-target more visible to search engines, so I am inclined to leave things as they are (i.e. the newer question closed as a duplicate of the older question).

A possible drawback to this approach is that closure is often just a waystation on the road to deletion. If the newer question attracted answers before its closure that the older question didn't, then merger could preserve content that would be subject to risk of deletion after closure.

@GerryMyerson Sure, but dupe closed questions are harder to delete (i.e. they won't be Roomba'd), and the community generally deletes dupe-closed questions less often.
